# How to modify specific item in list of list using list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am just wondering if there is any better way of modifying the specific item in the list of list using List comprehension?
In below example, I am squaring the second item of each list inside list, but, I don't want to eliminate inner list comprehension.

```
l = [
[1,2,3,],
[4,5,6,],
[7,8,9,],
]

nl = [[num**2 if i==1 else num for i, num in enumerate(x)] for x in l]
print nl
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify `l` in-place or create a new list `nl` with list comprehension?

Comment: Did you try `for x in l: x[1] = x[1]**2`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to keep the inner comprehension but you could do something like this:

```
def square_idx_one(sl):
    sl[1] **= 2
    return sl

l = [
[1,2,3,],
[4,5,6,],
[7,8,9,],
]

nl = [square_idx_one(sl) for sl in l]
print (nl)
```

result:

```
[[1, 4, 3], [4, 25, 6], [7, 64, 9]]
```

But if you're modifying the original I think a for loop probably edges this solution for performance, not to mention memory

Answer (score 2):

In your case, simply

```
print [[x, y**2, z] for x, y, z in l]
```

would do the job and says more explicitly what is going on. In general, do

```
from itertools import izip
p = (1, 2, 1) # element 0 power 1
#             # element 1 power 2
#             # element 2 power 1
# ...
print [[x**power for x, power in izip(row, p)] for row in l]
```

Comment: For this specific example, yes, but it doesn't scale well.